# Postfix - gmail encryption

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04, gmail

My server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have Postfix installed. When I send something to my gmail account, it goes to spam. I set up SPF, DKIM and DMARC, here is a confirmation:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of office@mydomain.com designates xxx.xxx.xx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=office@mydomain.com;
   dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
```

But there's a red padlock saying: `encryption: mydomain.com did not encrypt this message`.

Emails from others have such a note: `encryption: Standard (TLS)`

Could you help me a little with this, what should I do? Might it be a reason that emails from my server go to spam? Thanks in advance.

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.com, bociuch, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

Comment: Your postfix config would be helpful.

Comment: My initial post updated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are missing the [`smtp_tls_security_level`](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_levels) directive.

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

This will set it to opportunistic TLS, using encrypted connections if the server supports it, but allowing unencrypted connections if the server doesn't.

The default value for `smtp_tls_security_level` is `none`.

Comment: After adding it, everything works fine. Many thanks!

Comment: after 14 hours of knocking my head with gmail....its a shame i cant vote up u only one time... or not?

Comment: Surely you can figure out some way MacGyver ;)

Comment: Wow, what simple..., I wonder why the default isn't "may" for this option.